# Creating a tracking variable in a NFT

Tags: solidity, nft

How do I create a variable specific for each address, such that it increases when a certain function is preformed. For example, how many NFTs did a user mint?

This is what I did so far:

In the ERC721 contract I defined a mapping and a function which retunrs the number of _mints.

```
mapping(address => uint256) private _mints;
function Mints(address owner) public view virtual override returns (uint256) {
        require(owner != address(0), "ERC721: balance query for the zero address");
        return _mints[owner];
}
```

1.How do I access _mints variable and do some logic over it in the safemint function in MyNFT contract?

2.How do I change the _mints variable in MyNFT contract?

```
contract MyToken is ERC721, Pausable, Ownable, ERC721Burnable {
    constructor() ERC721("MyToken", "MTK") {}

    function pause() public onlyOwner {
        _pause();
    }

    function unpause() public onlyOwner {
        _unpause();
    }

    function safeMint(address to, uint256 tokenId) public onlyOwner {
        _safeMint(to, tokenId);
    }

    function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId)
        internal
        whenNotPaused
        override
    {
        super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Private variables and mappings Solidity is only usable within the contract in which they are defined. They are inaccessible to outside contracts or accounts. To access the data from outside the contract, you can, however, design a getter function inside it that returns the value of a private variable or mapping.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract MyContract {
    mapping(address => uint256) private myMapping;
    uint256 private myVariable;

    function getMappingValue(address _address) public view returns (uint256) {
        return myMapping[_address];
    }

    function getVariableValue() public view returns (uint256) {
        return myVariable;
    }
}
```

the private myMapping mapping's associated value is returned by the getMappingValue method after receiving an address as input. The private myVariable's value is all that the getVariableValue method returns. To recover the confidential information, these functions can be used outside of the contract.